# What is the difference between loading properties files in spring through @propertysource annotation and by using PropertySourcesHolderConfigure bean

Tags: java, spring, properties-file, spring-annotations

I am studying about how to access properties files in Spring and I am very confused to find out the difference among `<context:property-placeholder>` vs `PropertySourcesPlaceHoderConfigure` vs `@PropertySource` vs `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigure`.

Answer (score 0):

From [PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html)

PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer is more flexible and interacts with Environment and PropertySource. It can be local properties or system properties or environment variables.

> Specialization of `PlaceholderConfigurerSupport` that resolves `${...}` placeholders within bean definition property values and @Value annotations against the current `Spring Environment` and its set of `PropertySources`.

Answer (score 0):

**PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer**

We use PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer when we need to load some property files whose properties are used in applicationcontext.xml of spring. We can use the properties directly using JSTL expressions.

**@PropertySource**

This annotation contributes properties to the active [Spring environment](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html).

**context:property-placeholder**

Registers a component which can resolve placeholders of form ${propertyname} in bean definitions. It is intelligent enough to know that it needs to look not just at the properties registered through its location attribute but also to look at the properties available in the current active environment (which properties have been added in through the `@PropertySource` annotations).

Comment: Thanks Amogh for your answer but i have one doubt which component (bean) will be registered by context:property-placeholder

Comment: @sandy `<context:property-placeholder/>` is the XML equivalent to the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`

Comment: means the bean which registered through **<context:property-placeholder/>** is `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer `  from 3.1 PropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigure is the replacement of **PropertyPlaceHolderConfigure** so is there any difference between the two.

Comment: I don't think so. `context:property-placeholder` is just xml based solution for the same.

Comment: Thanks @Amogh .What about the `@value` annotation role in both `propertyplaceholderconfigure` and `PropertSourcesplaceholderConfigure` .